# What is the use of document.frmReport

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me the use of `document.frmReport` in JavaScript code?

My application uses this but I don't have any information about this.  Besides, it is an HTML DOM object from what I've searched on the internet.  A speedy answer would be very helpful.  The code is like this:

```
function fnAddItems(strSource,strTarget)
{
    var f = document.frmReport;
    var doAdd;
    var objSourceCombo  = eval("document.frmReport."+strSource);
    var objTargetCombo  = eval("document.frmReport."+strTarget);
    var selSourceLen  = objSourceCombo.length;
    var selTargetLen  = objTargetCombo.length; 
    var strSourceText;
    var strSourceValue;
    var arrIDs;
    var arrIDs1;
    var IsMultipleSelected;
    var strFormat;
}
```

Comment: You might want to add additional tags to your question. Currently you have only tagged it with "sqlite", although your issue seems more to do with javascript.

Comment: Can you show us some of the code in question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.frmReport` returns `undefined` for me. Also, there's no official documentation about it, and it's not in the specs.

So my guess is it's something that's added to the `document` object earlier in your application by someone else, and is being used now.

Look for `document.frmReport = something (probably an object)`

Do you understand why relying on `eval` and global variables is a bad practice now?